# Como fazer menu funcionar para link externo

Tags: javascript

Estou utilizando o seguinte script para fazer um efeito de deslizamento entre as seções do meu site (links com ancoras. P.E. #contato). No entando no meu menu tem um link externo, como faço para ele funcionar?

```
$(function() {

var navH = $('body > .nav').outerHeight(true);

$('body').css({
"margin-top": navH + "px"
});

$('body > nav .container-fluid .navbar-collapse .nav ').on("click", 'a', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();

var target = $(this).attr("href"),
  elementOffset = $(target).offset().top,
  distance = (elementOffset - navH);

$("html, body").stop(true, true).animate({
  scrollTop: distance
}, '500', 'swing', function() {
  $('body > .nav .active').removeClass("active");
  $('a[href="' + target + '"]').parent().addClass('active');
});
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Resolvido. Inclui a classe "desliza" na linha:

```
$('body > nav .container-fluid .navbar-collapse .nav .desliza ').on("click", 'a', function(e) {
```

e nas tags < li > antes dos link.

```
<li class="desliza">
```